# Display visited user stats on frontend in shopify

Tags: shopify

I need to display visited user stats like visitor counter (how many visitor visit) today or in particular time span on frontend in shopify.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify API doesn't provide this data. You can use an external service by adding a JS on your theme.liquid which records/saves your visitors activity on external database.